# Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Windows.Forms.Label]' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'

Tags: c#, winforms

```
   int iCnt = 1;
   foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
          {
             int val = Convert.ToInt32(dr[1]);
             int ack_val = Convert.ToInt32(dr[4]);

           
           string lblname = "alert" + iCnt;
           string btname = "bt" + iCnt;
           var labels =this.Controls.OfType<Label>()
            .Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith(lblname));
           var btns = this.Controls.OfType<Button>()
            .Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith(btname));

          if (val >= threshold && ack_val == 0)
           {
           ( (Label)labels).Show();
            ((Button)btns).Visible = true;

             }

            else
           {


            ((Label)labels).Hide();
         ((Button)btns).Visible = false;
            }
           iCnt++;
            }
```

I want to hide respective labels and buttons based on the condition. If the value from my data is greater than threshold value, then I want to display respective label and button for  that data row.

Comment: `.Where(` filters an enumerable, it doesn't return one object. You could use `.First` / `.Single`. Though I would recommend explicitly creating an array instead. `var buttons = new Button[]{ bt1, bt2, .... };`

Comment: I also found one more thing from your suggestion. How to loop the button array just to get the required btn?

Comment: this.Controls["alert" + iCnt.ToString()] works for my use case.